# Britishism: see you fast

Tags: british-english, dialects, idiom-meaning

In Season Two Episode One of *Happy Valley*, the mentor constable explains to the new recruit how helpful it is to have a good relationship with the receptionist, Joyce:

> Oh, and get well in with Joyce, she knows everybody and everything, and she'll never **see you fast.**

What is "see you fast"?

What I tried: idioms.thefreedictionary.com (both *see* and *fast* pages).

The story takes place in West Yorkshire.

---

I wonder if it has something to do with *fasting* as in *going without food*.

Comment: Why does this *have* to be a British expression? I would have immediately assumed it was using *going without food* figuratively. As in, *she'll never see you lacking (or wanting)*. The expression *see you fast* is certainly one I've heard many times before in a literal sense, so that immediately came to mind.

Comment: @JasonBassford - It's a conjecture, based on the program (programme) taking place and having been written and produced in the UK, combined with my English being the US variety.  The mentor and the new recruit both seemed quite comfortable with the expression.  I have had to watch the program with the English subtitles turned on -- otherwise I would have missed a lot of the dialogue.

Comment: But what I'm saying is that it (to me, anyway) makes just as much sense from a US perspective.

Comment: @JasonBassford - Would you like to contribute an answer?

Comment: It's not an idiom I recognise in spite of having lived not that far from the south part of the West Riding all my life. However I do recognise the expressions "stuck fast" meaning "in insurmountable difficulty". This is particularly recognisable as part of the expression "She (or he) won't see you stuck fast". I believe that the script writers for _Happy Valley_ were using it in that sense.

Answer (score 6):

*fast* in British dialect seems to mean *perplexed*

from *The English Dialect Dictionary* by Joseph Wright, 1900.

[image]

[Link to book entry and page](https://books.google.com/books?id=2YJBAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA305&dq=%22see%20you%20fast%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihtralgafjAhWSHTQIHc5pB6UQ6wEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22see%20you%20fast%22&f=false)

This text includes the definition *To be (or get) fast among it; to be embarrassed, puzzled, or at a standstill,*  as in the phrase *to be fast for, to be at a loss for, to be in want of.*

The phrase "see you fast" also occurs in some modern lyrics, but can't tell whether they're using the word this way.

In any case the meaning is that the secretary will never let the recruit be in a quandary.

Comment: I think the link is broken.

Comment: Which "British dialect"? I've certainly never heard the expression.

Comment: I would delete the reference to modern lyrics, it should be clear whether the meaning of "fast=puzzled/standstill" is being used that way, looking up the song lyrics ought to be enough. As for the second link, I am in Italy and the link to the dictionary page is not view-able. Have you tried the Internet Archive?

Comment: @WS2 I have no idea which dialect.  This is a multi-volume dictionary published by an Oxford scholar in 1900, but it has quotations, sources, and symbols (e.g., nYks) and seems to be a careful job.  This volume covers D-G only.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I don't know about the Internet Archive; the NGram search is just "see you fast", and if you choose the years around 1900, there's only one source that's not a false positive.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/englishdialectdi02wrig/page/305

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the link--that is splendid.

Comment: @mari-Lou And thanks for the edit.

Comment: I would still delete reference to lyrics unless you can find any that confirm this meaning, which would be excellent! I imagine that the lyrics would mention things like "**see you fast asleep**"

Comment: @WS2 'Yks' obviously means Yorkshire. I admit I've never heard the expression either, even though my mum came from there.

Comment: In the context, *embarrassed* fits well.  Thank you.

Comment: My guess it comes from fast as in 'stuck fast'

Answer (score -1):

A lyrics reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcQ0kMK0pow

"Hey, I see you fast today,
But I much to much
I'm missing you
At the moment the day breaks"

Comment: Given that the lyrics don't really make sense, I'm not sure how this helps answer the question.

Comment: @KillingTime It's obviously connected, but only adds anecdotal evidence. A reasonable 'comment'. And the tune's not bad.